# Make 100 with only 9 numbers

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Make 100 with ONLY 9 numbers

Hint 1:

> They all have something in common

Hint 2:

> The first 4 are numbers digits, the rest are not.

Hint 3:

> + =(use addition)

Hint 4:

> They are the 1st ___(<-- what kind?) numbers

Comment: I'm not really clear on the rules here....

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! As it stands, your question has way too many possible answers - there are many ways to make 100 with 9 numbers. If you have additional restrictions on what those numbers can be, and the allowed ways of combining them, those must be specified in the main body of the question.

Comment: I think your "hints" need to be actual rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I guess we are talking about the:

> prime numbers. The sum of the first 9 equals 100 (2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23 = 100) and also the first 4 of them are also digits.