# Marking the Occasion

Tags: riddle

> I don't have any letters.
>   I used to have one letter (and a dash).
>   If you run, I have one letter (and a digit).
>   When I have twelve letters, no two of them are the same.

What am I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't have any letters.

> 5000 - just numbers.

I used to have one letter (and a dash).

> $\overline V$ - Roman numeral for 5000.

If you run, I have one letter (and a digit).

> 5k - a running event.

When I have twelve letters, no two of them are the same.

> five thousand - the largest isogrammic number (no repeating letters).

Title - Marking the Occasion

> This is the 5000th [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) question!

Comment: Spot on! The title refers to a (precisely) concurrent event though. :-)

Comment: Ha! @Bass you must have had this one up your sleeve for a little while, nervously watching that tag count!

Comment: @Stiv Exactly the opposite, actually! I was cleaning up tags (on a [pure formation-of-numbers question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92813/36023)), when I noticed that I'd just *removed* the crucial tag, so I figured I had about half an hour to come up with a suitable riddle to claim it for myself. Checking my activity list, it took about 27 minutes; pure luck really, that nobody happened to post during that time :-)

Comment: @Tom, Question: How does one determine your last reason?  rot13(Jurer vf gur Cbfg Ahzore qvfcynlrq?)

Comment: @B540Glenn - Its shows my desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuagE.png on clicking the tag but not on my mobile.

Comment: @tom Since your picture shows "sorted by active", which constitutes only an incomplete proof, [here's mine](https://i.imgur.com/Ce5K9tH.png) from the time just after posting.